# SQL Numbering of non-sequential Groups

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me with a select statement that will return the "Section" numbering I have shown below? I found some similar questions and answers but nothing that addresses my specific requirements.

My data (simplified for this example) are the "Sequence" and "Data" columns and I want to produce the "Section" column, based on:

1. my data being ordered by the value in the Sequence column, and
2. based on the break in value of the Data column:

[image]

Note that the "Section" numbering I desire breaks on the "change in value" of the Data column with no consideration for the actual values in that column or for them having to be in any particular sequence.

I should also clarify that the values in the Sequence column will be contiguous so no missing numbers in the sequence, which the chosen answer satisfies.

Comment: use `row_number... partition by Data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the difference in row number method here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sequence) -
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Data ORDER BY Sequence) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Sequence, Data, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rn) AS Section
FROM cte
ORDER BY Sequence;
```

[image]

### Demo

It is difficult to explain in words why this method works here, but if you are curious, you may try `SELECT * FROM cte` to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

this solution uses the window function twice.

```
-- [2] then use dense_rank() on the smallest sequence by Data
select  *, dense_rank() over(order by s)
from
(
    -- [1] find the smallest Sequence for each group of Data
    select  *, s = min(Sequence) over (partition by Data)
    from    tbl
) t
order by Sequence
```